# The different between Web Performance Test and App Insight

Tags: win-universal-app

Currently, I had used WinJS to developed UWP app.
I saw the tutorial of Azure Web Performance Test and App Insight.
I confuse each of them, what are the different of both?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a C# UWP application, Visual Studio has an option to integrate Application Insights for your project.

Unfortunately, you don’t have that same option when using UWP in HTML/JavaScript. In that case, you will have to do all plumbing manually. Microsoft provide a SDK for using Application Insight in JavaScript.

We wrote small a wrapper for JavaScript sdk that adds those metadata and everything starts working fine for HTML/JavaScript UWP apps.

http://mcnextpost.com/2015/10/26/uwphtml-using-application-insights-in-your-windows-web-applications/